# Image doesn't get focus on click

Tags: c#, wpf, click, focus, snoop

I have WPF application in which there are some controls on a screen layer. 
Navigating between the controls using TAB (keyboard) works appropriately, and I can see the image gets focus using SNOOP.
BUT - Clicking the image doesn't set the focus on it.

If it matters - I enter a function I need via both (click and enter) events handlers... Just the focus is not being recieved in the click case, that's the confusion I can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a templated Button to show your image? You get the focus-on-click behavior, but show an image:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Image Source="http://placehold.it/300x500" Stretch="Fill" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Image` element doesn't get focused by default when you click on it. You could write some code that focuses it though. Just handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event:

```
private void img_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = sender as Image;
    img.Focusable = true;
    img.Focus();
}
```

---

```
<Image Source="pic.png" MouseLeftButtonDown="img_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
```